# I want to add Text below Currency Select Box Magento, how do I do it?

Tags: magento, currency

I have a currency select box on my magento install.  It is located exactly where I want it and all is good.

However I want to add a piece of text below the drop down select box just telling people that they will be charged in NZD.

Problem is I have edited app\design\frontend\base\default\template\directory\currency.phtml but no changes happen on the front end.

I have even changed **__('Select Your Currency') ?>** to **__('HEY') ?>** Just to see would it work and nothing, it didn't change the header of the box at all.

Please help, what am I doing wrong, am I am idiot?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you clear cache after applying changes ?

Answer (score 1):

Hii Instead of using base theme try changing in your current working theme it will reflect

For ex:-

\app\design\frontend\yourtheme\yourtheme\template\directory\currency.phtml

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

1. Are you modifying base theme for all your template requirement.This is not Magento standard practice.
2. Switch on Hints and check the block and html involved. Modify that .phtml ot write some code in associated block file and call that block function from your .phtml